# Altering an input in JS, and then editing a php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am quite new to coding, and have been trying to figure out how to do this for a while now, and cannot seem to figure it out. So I have an HTML form inside of a PHP file. This is currently what my input form with CSS looks like.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@600&display=swap');

.maincatalougetable {
    border: 3px black solid;
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    margin-left: 13%;
    width: 20%;
}
.bodytitle {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.bodysubtitle {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.td, th {
    border: 2px solid #3a2e2e;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
.background {
    background-color: rgb(61, 61, 145);
}
.body {
    background-color: rgb(212, 195, 195);
    border: 3px solid blueviolet;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%
}
.hr {
    width: 10%;
}
.plateactimg {
    width: 150px;
    padding: -10px;
}
.basictitle {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
}
.basicinput {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.inputbody {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.postbutton {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    border: 3px rgb(0, 174, 255) solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.postbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgb(147, 147, 187);
    transition: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.adminheader {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: -34px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: 101%;
}
.admintitle {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.basicfile {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    border: 3px rgb(0, 174, 255) solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.basicfile:hover {
    background-color: rgb(147, 147, 187);
    transition: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="inputbody">
    <div class="adminheader">
        <h1 class="admintitle">Administrator Panel</h1>
    </div>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <label class="basictitle" for="type">Type (i.e. Yukon Passenger Plate):</label><br>
        <input class="basicinput" type="text" id="type" name="type"><br>

        <label class="basictitle" for="year">Year:</label><br>
        <input class="basicinput" type="text" id="year" name="year"><br>

        <label class="basictitle" for="condition">Condition:</label><br>
        <input class="basicinput" type="text" id="condition" name="condition"><br>
    
        <label class="basictitle" for="platenumber">Plate Number (i.e. 1-283):</label><br>
        <input class="basicinput" type="text" id="platenumber" name="platenumber"><br>

        <label class="basictitle" for="price">Price (Without shipping costs):</label><br>
        <input class="basicinput" type="text" id="price" name="price"><br>

        <label class="basictitle" for="imagepath">Image File Name (With the extension i.e. yukon1.png):</label><br>
        <input class="basicinput" type="text" id="price" name="price"><br>

        <label class="basictitle" for="misc">Miscellaneous (Optional):</label><br>
        <input class="basicinput" type="text" id="misc" name="misc"><br>
        <br>
        <input class="postbutton" type="submit" value="Upload">

        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" class="basicfile"mname="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So once you type in your desired input in the input boxes and upload you desired image, I would like a file in the main directory called 'maincatalougetable.php' to be altered in such a way that the inputs that were inputted in the forms in the file I showed above (called newlisting.php) will replace the undefined variables in the snippet shown below. I believe this can be accomplished by altering the text inputted in the forms with JS and then editing the maincatalougetable.php file so that it will show up in the main catalog. Below I have included the maincatalouge.php file, and how I want it to be altered. I think this is the best way to do what I want, but I am fairly new to this. Thank you!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@600&display=swap');

.maincatalougetable {
    border: 3px black solid;
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    margin-left: 13%;
    width: 20%;
}
.bodytitle {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.bodysubtitle {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.td, th {
    border: 2px solid #3a2e2e;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
.background {
    background-color: rgb(61, 61, 145);
}
.body {
    background-color: rgb(212, 195, 195);
    border: 3px solid blueviolet;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%
}
.hr {
    width: 10%;
}
.plateactimg {
    width: 150px;
    padding: -10px;
}
.basictitle {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
}
.basicinput {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.inputbody {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.postbutton {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    border: 3px rgb(0, 174, 255) solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.postbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgb(147, 147, 187);
    transition: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .adminheader {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: -34px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: 101%;
}
.admintitle {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.basicfile {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    border: 3px rgb(0, 174, 255) solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.basicfile:hover {
    background-color: rgb(147, 147, 187);
    transition: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table class="maincatalougetable">
    <tr>
        <th class="plateimagetag">Image</th>
        <th class="platenametag">Type</th>
        <th class="plateyeartag">Year</th>
        <th class="platecondtag">Condition</th>
        <th class="platenumbertag">Number</th>
        <th class="platepricetag">Price</th>
        <th class="platemisctag">Miscellaneous</th>
        <th class="platecontacttag">Inquire</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="plateimage"><img class="plateactimg" src="yukon1-762.JPG"> </th>
        <th class="platename">I want the plate name input from the newlisting.php file to show up here, and create new columns as more are added. </th>
        <th class="plateyear">I want the plate year input from the newlisting.php file to show up here, and create new columns as more are added.</th>
        <th class="platecond">I want the plate condition input from the newlisting.php file to show up here, and create new columns as more are added.</th>
        <th class="platenumber">I want the plate number input from the newlisting.php file to show up here, and create new columns as more are added.</th>
        <th class="plateprice">I want the plate price input from the newlisting.php file to show up here, and create new columns as more are added.</th>
        <th class="platemisc">I want the plate misc input from the newlisting.php file to show up here, and create new columns as more are added.</th>
        <th class="platecontact"><a href="mailto:safteyman@northwestel.net?subject=1960 Yukon Passenger Plate VG+">E-mail</a></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```